# how to transform each column of a dataframe from binary to byte array

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a dataset ds1 with following schema

```
root
 |-- binary_col1: binary (nullable = true)
```

which i transform as needed using

```
val ds2 = ds1.map(row => row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("binary_col1"))
```

But how do I transform the dataset when it has two columns of binary type ?

```
root
 |-- binary_col1: binary (nullable = true)
  -- binary_col2: binary (nullable = false)
```

I want to create new dataset with 2 columns
(  binary_col1.toByteArray , binary_col2.toByteArray)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as` on the dataframe/dataset, and provide a tuple2 type:

```
val ds2 = ds1.as[(Array[Byte], Array[Byte])]
```

This is better than using `map` because it preserves column names.

Of course, you can also use `map`, e.g.

```
val ds2 = ds1.map(row => (row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("binary_col1"), row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("binary_col2")))
```